# How to make label for radio button

Tags: css, html, c#-4.0, razorengine

I have some radio buttons. But I also want to the text clickable. So that the ratio button is selected. So not only if you click on the radio button that the ratio buttion is selected, but also if you click on the text, that the ratio button is selected.

I have this:

```
<td>
  <input id="upload" name="folder" type="radio" value="@item" />
  <label>@Html.Label(item)</label>
</td>
```

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Directories)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="upload" name="folder" type="radio" value="@item" />
                        <label for="upload">@Html.Label(item)</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have it now like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <table>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Directories)
                {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name="folder" value="@item" id="upload">
                                                        <label for="folder">@Html.Label(item)</label>
                                                    </label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                }
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

but the radio buttons are in a foreach loop, so the id is different of every radio button

I try it like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <table>
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.Directories)
                {
                                          @for(var i=0; i < item.Count; i++){
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>


                                                        <fieldset>
                                                            <input type="radio" name="folder" value="@item" id="folder">
                                                            <label for="folder">@Html.Label(item)</label>
                                                        </fieldset>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                }
                                        }

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique. And assuming you have a loop, it is not.

Comment: Your code is perfect. Please mark a answer below as correct answer or they'll probably flood this question with same answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for` attribute with the value of the `input`'s `id` attribute:

```html
<input id="upload" name="folder" type="radio" value="@item" />
<label for="upload">@Html.Label(item)</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

the simple way

```html
    <td>
      <label>
      <input id="upload" name="folder" type="radio" value="@item" />
       @Html.Label(item)</label>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `label for`

```html
<td>
  <input id="upload" name="folder" type="radio" value="@item" />
  <label for="upload">@Html.Label(item)</label>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` attribute:

```
<label for="folder">@Html.Label(item)</label>
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post, YOu can click on it. But the button is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the radio within a label tag, To display some text add a  tag inside the label:

```
<label for="upload">
  <span>@Html.Label(item)</span>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="folder" value="@item" id="upload" >
```

Comment: Thank you, I can click on it, but the ratio button is not selected